# Visual Studio Test Pro + TestComplete

Tags: visual-studio-2010

So first off, I did a terrible job researching Test Pro before talking bosses into buying it.
The intent was to start using it on some of our SL apps since TestComplete has been troublesome for our tester.

My mistake was assuming and not looking to confirm if Coded UI tests where part of that package. I have to say I really like all the features, but it seems silly not to include the part need for true automation. So enough self pity and ranting. :-)

Has anyone had any good or bad experience combining TestComplete scripts in with VS Test Pro 2010?  I would like to salvage something out of my screw up, but I'm afraid it may complicate the overall process to a point where we're not gaining anything.

Also I would like to avoid buying another VS Premium.